# Dynamical system and attractors

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact metrizable space and $T : X → X$ a continuous map. We think of $T$
as the transition map of a discrete-time dynamical system with state space $X$. Namely, starting from a state $x$,
the system evolves by first going to state $T(x)$, then to state $T^2(x)$, and so on and so forth.
A closed subset $U ⊆ X$ is said to be inward if $T(U) ⊆ int(U)$. Observe that if $U$ is inward, then $U ⊇ T(U) ⊇ T^2(U) ⊇ · · ·$ . A set $A ⊆ X$ is called an attractor if $A =\cap_{n=0}^∞T^n(U)$ for some inward $U ⊆ X$.

$(a)$ Consider the map $T : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ defined by $T(x) := x^2$

Show that $A_1 :=$ {$0$} and $A_2 := [0, 1]$ are
attractors but $A_3 :=$ {$1$} is not.

$(b)$ Show that every attractor is non-empty.

$(c)$ Let $U$ be an inward set and $A$ the associated attractor.

Show that for every open set $B ⊇ A$, there exists
an $n ∈ \mathbb N$ such that $T^n(U) ⊆ B$

My attempts:

$(b)$ I'll prove this hy contradiction. Suppose that every attractor is empty, i.e. for $A ⊆ X$, we have $A =\cap_{n=0}^∞T^n(U) = \phi$ for some inward $U ⊆ X$. But then this means that $A = U \cap T(U) \cap T^2(U) \cap ... \cap T^n(U) = \phi$, and this means that the $T^n(U)$'s for $n \in \mathbb N$ don't have any elements in common. However, $U ⊇ T(U) ⊇ T^2(U) ⊇ · · ·$ so they indeed have elements in common. Therefore, every attractor is non-empty.

$(c)$ We are given an open set $B ⊇ A$, thus $A =\cap_{n=0}^∞T^n(U) ⊆ B$, and this means that $A = U \cap T(U) \cap T^2(U) \cap ... \cap T^n(U) ⊆ B$. Let $x \in U \cap T(U) \cap T^2(U) \cap ... \cap T^n(U) ⊆ B$, thus $x \in U$, and $x \in T(U)$, and $x \in T^2(U)$,..., and $x \in T^n(U)$, also $x \in B$. Thus, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $T^n(U) ⊆ B$

Are parts $(b)$ and $(c)$ correct?

$(a)$ I don't know how to solve it, any help please?

Comment: Do not completely change your question. Particularly don't do that after you've got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For $a)$, see that
$$A_1 = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)$$
$$A_2 = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$$

but $A_3=\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ cannot be written like this. Indeed, the only subset $U$ of $[0,1]$ such that $A_3 = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n(U)$ is $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$, but $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ is not inward (since it has empty interior).

Comment: Deal, thank you. Are parts b and c correct?

Comment: For $b$, you need to be must precise. Why do the $T^n(U)$'s have an element in common ? The fact that there are inclusions is not sufficient... (imagine for ewemple that $T^n(U)=[n,+\infty)$). You must use that $X$ is compact.

Comment: So the fact that $X$ is compact, means that $X$ is closed and bounded, and so the $T^n(U)$'s have an element in common?

Comment: Yes. Try to prove this using the Borel-Lebesgue definition of compacity (with covers and subcovers)

Comment: Okay, thank you! And what about part $(c)$

Comment: @CarlitoFernandez your proof of part $c$ is not convincing either. The $x$ you take is not *every* $x$ in $T^n(U)$, so it's not sufficient to prove that $x \in B$ for this $x$ to deduce that $T^n(U) \subset B$. You must again use the compacity of $X$ here. To be familiar with the arguments involved in both parts $b$ and $c$, have a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem